# Dynamic ASP Form Post - Without Using an Iframe

Tags: asp.net, forms, post, iframe

I need to modify a 3-level dropdown `<select>` menu to function directly on the page and not inside an iframe (that's how we currently do it).

Here's how this menu works:

1. User makes a selection in 1st dropdown
2. Choices in 2nd dropdown are filtered based on what's chosen in 1st one; user selects from one of these choices
3. Choices in 3rd dropdown are filtered based on what's chosen in 2nd one; user selects from one of these choices; this last dropdown submits the form and redirects the user to another page, also passing the values from all three dropdowns.

Right now, this is accomplished using an `<iframe>` that queries an ASP.net database and reloads itself after each selection.

I really need it to work without using an iframe. Not sure what the most elegant way to approach this is ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're open to using the ASP.NET Ajax Toolkit, they have a [cascading dropdown control](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/CascadingDropDown/CascadingDropDown.aspx) which does what you ask. One additional benefit, because it uses Ajax it does not have to reload the page after each selection in the dropdowns.

Answer (score 0):

i think you'll probably need to use the 'onSelectIndexChanged` even on the DropDownList control. something like...

```
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl1" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl1_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl2" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl2_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>
<asp:DropDownList id="ddl3" runat="server"  OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddl3_OnSelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList>

Page_Load()
{
    if(!IsPostBack)
    {
        ddl1.DataSource = getdata();
        ddl1.DataBind();
}

protected void ddl1_onSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl2.DataSource = getData(ddl1.SelectedValue);
    ddl2.DataBind()
}
protected void ddl1_onSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ddl3.DataSource = getData(ddl2.SelectedValue);
    ddl3.DataBind()
}
protected void ddl3_onSelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("SomePage.aspx?ddl1="+ddl1.SelectedValue+"&ddl2="+ddl2.SelectedValue+"&ddl3="+ddl3.SelectedValue, true);
}
```

Comment: I am sure he is already doing that. His problem is partially refreshing the page, not changing the content.

Answer (score 0):

You could put all 3 of them in an UpdatePanel.

I am sure your changes are already making the page refresh.
Putting them in an update panel will make only the panel refresh, causing a partial page update.

This uses ajax to do the job internally.

Here is a [update panel example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001.aspx), if you want one.

P.s.: Asp.net's method to create a `<select>` is a `DropDownList` control. I hope you are already using those, if not convert your selects to a dropdownlists.